# Compiled with problems: × ERROR - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-lifecycle-hooks

## I want to use nativeElement in ngOnInit but i can't able to use in lifecycle. It throws an error.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '\[setBackground\]'
})
export class SetBackgroundDirective implements OnInit {
    private element: ElementRef | undefined;
    constructor(element: ElementRef) {
        this.element = element;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, provide more information.

Comment: You defined the field as potential undefined and ask why you get the error? :) Well either do not define as potential undefined and ensure it is defined or add a check in ngOnInit.